# Matrix Derivatives In Back-propagation: Matrix times vector

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, machine-learning

I am currently performing back-propagation on a neural network by hand and am perform derivatives on matrices. How would I calculate $\frac{d}{dh_a}(W_xX + W_hh_a + h_bh_a)$ where $W_x$ is 3x3 matrix, $X$ is vector of length 3, $W_x$ is a $3x3$ matrix, $h_a$ is a vector of length 3, and $h_b$ is a vector of length 3.

I assume that the derivative would equal to $Wh + h_b$ when thinking in a scalar perspective, but this does not seem to the correct. How would I go about calculating this derivative?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus for specific indentities that might be useful. In general, the way I approach this is to first compute the _differential_, then generate the required derivative from that. Much less opportunity for error, I find.

Comment: If all other matrices involved are constant in $h_a$, then you conjecture is correct, but the convention is to derive a column vector with respect to row vectors (or conversely). It clumsy to write your product as $h_a h_b$, usually we write $h_a h_b^T$.